# After maximize google map window, autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm trying to use google map with mvc in my project.
I can find the location by typing in textbox while map is **minimized**.
The location is showed automatically.
However the location isn't showed automatically in the **maximize** state.

Here is my code :

```
    function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 13
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        draggable: true,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });
    var input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    //Set initial restrict countries.
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions(
        { 'country': ['mm'] });
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        infowindow.close();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
        }
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);
        infowindow.setContent(place.formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

    });
    // this function will work on marker move event into map 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': marker.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Screenshot : 
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sVhw.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyh29.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `z-index` for `.pac-container` that is above the map (**warning undocumented behavior, may change with future releases of the API**)

```
.pac-container {
  z-index: 2147483648;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8xLbzf6q/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.958828, 96.089103);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 13
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    draggable: true,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });
  var input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  //Set initial restrict countries.
  autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
    'country': ['mm']
  });
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);
    infowindow.setContent(place.formatted_address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

  });
  // this function will work on marker move event into map 
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'latLng': marker.getPosition()
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
          infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#searchInput {
  top: 15px;
  left: 120px;
}

.pac-container {
  z-index: 2147483648;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="searchInput" />
<div id="map"></div>
```